# "no such file or directory" when using cd command in terminal mac

Tags: terminal, cd

There seems to be something wrong when a try to run cd command in the terminal. The terminal says "no such file or directory", even though I'm sure the directory exists and that I'm using the correct pathway. I've read that some of the newer versions of macOS can have these problems, could that be it? I'm using macOS Monterey Version 12.3.1. I'm a beginner at python programming so I'm at a loss for what to do now. All help is welcome!

Comment: can you add a bit more details to the question as to what you tried? Maybe type `pwd` on your terminal and press Enter to see where you are? then `ls -l` to see all the files and directories? Finally, the `cd` command that you had problem with.

Would be great to see what the results and error texts are.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: So I'm furthest up in the root hierarchy, when I use ls I can see all the directories and files. I have allowed access files in my setting so it is not that either.

Comment: Here is the error message: cd: no such file or directory: /Desktop

Comment: The same error message shows when I try to access every other directory, except for applications.